# Append dynamically generated dijit to end of a div

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to create and append a dijit to the end of a div? Say I have the following code:

```
<div id="attendants">
</div>

<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="addPerson();">Add Person</button>
```

I found the following code online but this replaces my 'attendants' div:

```
var personCount = 0;
function addPerson() {
    personCount += 1;
    var attendants = dojo.byId('attendants');
    var newField   = new dijit.form.TextBox({id: 'newPerson' + personCount, name: 'newPerson' + personCount}, attendants);
}
```

and I want to dynamically add a new TextBox dijit to the div, not replace the div with a dijit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: [dijit._Widget.placeAt](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/dijit/1.2/dijit._Widget.placeAt)

```
// place a new button as the first element of some div
var button = new dijit.form.Button({ label:"click" }).placeAt("wrapper","first");
```

Comment: Just to be clear, since I wasn't able to find it in any documentation (this was the closest)....the return type is the dijit._Widget instance, not the domNode =)